# Vtiger6 how to integrate with existing website

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

I am confused as to the best way to integrate vtiger with my existing website's mysql db.

I have a mysql table called users.  The table contains all the expected fields of a user table such as username, email, password, created, modified, newsletter, etc. etc.  I have another table called membership which states when the user paid, how much and when his premium account will expire.

I would like to suck in all this info to manage in vtiger.  The first step would be to import all users' data.  After that, it would be a case of updating vtiger if any changes made to the users' record on the web db and vice versa.

What would be the best way to go about this?  What tools already exist?  Your comments would be very helpful as I have been searching everywhere to see how others have done this but cannot find any examples or ideas.  I am using redhat, Apache, mysql and php with vtiger6.

Comment: I dont think there is any tools to do the job. The vtiger user management is complicated it includes `role`,`profile` etc. Also note that the password for vtiger is uses a encryption algorithm. I would suggest to write a script to copy the users to `vtiger_users` table and you may need to generate the id by adding the entry in `vtiger_crmentity` table. Finally login as admin and then update the users once so that it creates the permission files for the users.

Comment: Seems to me there is quite some demand for a two-way sync tool. Excluding password fields, would have thought there would have been some tool out there to assist with syncing. Maybe an update or delete or insert in MySQL could trigger an update to vtiger or vica versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends by what version of vtiger do you use, and what kind of website model/infrastructure do you using.
For 100% website custom code you have 2 quickly ways:
- Talend ETL https://www.talend.com/ suggested for complex data mapping
- Mysql Triggers, (something like this http://blog.scarletkangaroo.com/2012/12/opencart-vtiger-syncmyshop-parte-1.html)

Good Luck! ;-)